# Nesting ListView in ScrollView - A subtle clarification

Tags: android

I've read many posts indicating how a ListView should not be nested within ScrollView.

I was wondering if this applies to all AdapterView's in general ?

It'd be helpful to know before finding out after writing a whole bunch of code for a custom list view that will be nested in a ScrollView. I want to base it on an AdapterView so that I can use it similarly to a standard ListView (to help minimize re-write of my current ListView related code).

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was wondering if this applies to all AdapterView's in general ?

On the whole, `ScrollView` does not play nice with the other kids.

> It'd be helpful to know before finding out after writing a whole bunch of code for a custom list view that will be nested in a ScrollView.

There is no need to put a `ListView` in a `ScrollView`. Just put the other stuff from the `ScrollView` into the `ListView` itself, either as header/footer views, or using [my `MergeAdapter`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge), or similar techniques.

> I want to base it on an AdapterView so that I can use it similarly to a standard ListView

Creating a custom `AdapterView` from scratch is not easy. If you look at the source for `ListView`, and its `AbsListView` immediate parent, there are several thousand lines of code. It would be much simpler to just put the contents of the `ScrollView` into the `ListView`, per my preceding paragraph.

Comment: I went ahead and followed this tutorial http://developer.sonymobile.com/2010/05/20/android-tutorial-making-your-own-3d-list-part-1/ (this link was posted here at SO as an answer to a related question). Putting this view in a scroll view yields the same behavior as a builtin ListView: collapsing lists.

Comment: The problem with the Header/Footer technique is that my "main" view is actually three separate lists, stacked vertically. Based on a new spec, I need to initially give each list a third of the vertical space, and include a down arrow in each header (these lists are non scrolling initially). If the down arrow is pressed, then that list expands, and now the entire screen becomes scroll-able (not the individual list). I guess I could make each list scroll-able, and behave like a frame in a webpage (I initially though that once the other lists got pushed off the screen they'd become unreachable).

Comment: @SamusArin: That sounds like three `ListViews` in a vertical `LinearLayout`, which itself is in a `FrameLayout`. On the header click, you reparent the selected `ListView` to be a later child of the `FrameLayout`, so that it fills the screen and overlays the other two `ListViews`. I fear that your proposed UI will be difficult to use on phones -- either your rows will be too small or the three-stacked-lists view will have little content besides the headers. Also, the user may not understand how to return to the three-stacked-lists perspective (BACK button? something else?).

Comment: This version is for 10 inch tablets, in landscape (sorry forgot to mention). I will give your technique a shot. I think they got the idea from Ipad's GUI, and its a straight-forward idea, however android is still quite stringent (its ok, its still young). They'd have to scroll to the header and collapse.

Comment: @SamusArin: Bear in mind that there are approximately zero people on the planet who use both an iPad and a 10" Android tablet. Hence, the objective should not be "do the same thing as we would do on an iPad". The objective should be "do something that will be natural for users on Android". What you are describing may or may not be intuitive to Android users; I certainly cannot think of any apps that follow your described pattern. This has nothing to do with Android being "stringent" or "young".

Comment: We'll, by stringent I meant that it doesn't (easily) allow for a simple concept such as this to be implemented, and by young I meant that its components seem desinged to be used in specific ways, where they should be more general and flexible (which I'd hope they'd be as they mature). However, this is really due to the "bug"/incompatibility of ListView's within ScrollViews.

Comment: Can I nest three child ListView's within a parent ListView, where the parent does the scrolling and the child ListView's scrolling will be disable (by overriding the touch events and stuff) ?

Comment: Sounds like android directly supports this concept, partially with ExpandableListView's http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

Comment: @SamusArin: I look at `ExpandableListView` as being closer to a tree widget. "Can I nest three child ListView's within a parent ListView , where the parent does the scrolling and the child ListView's scrolling will be disable (by overriding the touch events and stuff) ?" -- then just have one `ListView`. You gain nothing but complexity for doing that over using `MergeAdapter`, for the same visual results.

Comment: The single ListView would work perfectly if I could somehow make sections of it collapse. Do you know of a way to do this ? I would separate the sections by inserting a header/separater between each "sublist"/section that would respond to click events that would (hopefully) "collapse"/hide that "sublist". Thanks.

Comment: @SamusArin: "but is very specialized due to this constraint" -- I like to think of it as a very short tree. :-) "the ELV Adapter's constructor takes a context of type Context" -- call `getActivity()` on a fragment to get the hosting `Activity`, which is a `Context`.

Comment: We'll, ELV has only 1 level of nesting, so yeah, in general its an instance of a tree widget, but is very specialized due to this constraint. It is this constraint that makes it a perfect match for what I need, however the problem I'm facing is that I'm using it within a Fragment, and the ELV Adapter's constructor takes a context of type Context, where a Fragments context is of whatever type the Fragment happens to be (you use the this pointer as the context within fragments). I might get it working.

Comment: Ahh, its that easy to get the Context in a Fragment !!! Thanks man. I've dealt with this issue before, but I restructured my code since then (not to avoid this, for other reasons) and I ended up not needing the Application context anymore (the local Fragment on sufficed). This is soo good to know, thanks a lot!

Comment: It works (the ExpandleListView), thanks so much for all the help and all the great suggestions. I'll will definitely give some of your idea's a shot whenever a new problem calls for them.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be work if you want to nest ListView within ScrollView. It's simple to use as it's extends ListView and only override one method.

The only bug is you may need to use `scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 0)`to set the scrolled position to head.

```
public class ScrollListView extends ListView{
    public ScrollListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ScrollListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ScrollListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2,
            MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);
    }
}
```

At last, set the scrolled position to head.

```
scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 0)
```